# How to Use DragDrop in AIR Application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I am building an AIR application which opens some specific documents. I want to enable dragdrop on this application. So that when application is running and user drag a file and drop that file on the application window, the application must respond to that event and must be able to perform some action. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a NativeDrag manager with specific settings in application.xml

You can see more details at http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/drag-drop-of-a-file-into-an-air-app-beta-3/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [Invoke event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/InvokeEvent.html).

Comment: application is already invoked. But when I drag a file and drop on application window, it does not respond. I want to enable this event and also handle this event. Thanks

Comment: application invoked means that the application is already running. I think I should rephrase my question. Application is already running, I just want to catch the event when some file is dragged from disk and dropped on running application.Thanks

Comment: Then you'll need the native drag drop `this.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP,onDrop);`

Comment: I added this event listener in the start. But when I dragged the file from disk and dropped on application window, It did not do anything. I did this: <this.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP, onDragDrop);>

Comment: the the start of what?  What are you attaching it to? Have you tried looking at the documentation for the event? Did it compile properly? etc etc